# Can we club parallel request in JMeter during recording

Tags: jmeter

I am testing an application which invokes groups of parallel http requests during multiple-page navigation.

To mimic real user behaviour I want to club the requests hitting the server parallel.
I know I can use the "Parallel controller" but for that, I need to see the developer tool and club them.

My **question** is **"Can we club parallel requests in JMeter during recording"** as in other load testing tools we have functions to club the parallel calls which attach to the script during the recording itself.

" *`The reason for this question is --> I am getting question from the developer that we can't accept the JMeter result as it does not mimic the real user behaviour(Brower behaviour)`*" Give me your thought on this also.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter neither can record nor replay parallel requests.

The build-in functionality allows simulating downloading of [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter) (images,scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc.) in parallel, however these resources should not be recorded. Parallel downloading can be enabled under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and/or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults).

[image]

If the real user sends network requests which are not related to the embedded resources, i.e. [AJAX requests](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) - JMeter will record them but will replay them sequentially, to mimic real browser's behaviour you will need to put them under the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller)